# I can't show a file path when click upload button

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin.forms

I followed the video tutorial Houssem Dellai about Upload File from Xamarin app to ASP.NET server on youtube.
here is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVvJX4CoLUY

My problem when i click button upload photo my code is only executed until

```
var httpResponseMessage = await httpclient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAddress, content);
```

And didn't show message error, my code cannot executed RemotePathFile.Text for show path file

This is my coding

```
private async void UploadFile_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        content.Add(new StreamContent(_mediaFile.GetStream()),
            "\"file\"",
            $"\"{_mediaFile.Path}\"");

        var httpclient = new HttpClient();

        var uploadServiceBaseAddress = "https://192.168.43.172/api/Files/Upload";

        var httpResponseMessage = await httpclient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAddress, content);

        RemotePathFile.Text = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    }
```

And This is my UploadController

```
public class UploadsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/Files/Upload")]
    public async Task<string> Post()
    {
        try
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];

                    var fileName = postedFile.FileName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault().Split('/').LastOrDefault();

                    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + fileName);

                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                    return "/Uploads/" + fileName;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return exception.Message;
        }

        return "no files";
    }
}
```

Please help me, how i can fix ?

Comment: are you sure PostAsync isn't throwing an exception, or timing out but you're not waiting long enough?

Comment: yes maybe PostAsync throwing an exception because 
i have waited a long time it is not response, Could you help me how to fix it ?

Comment: have you verified that your server is reachable from the device/emulator's browser?

Comment: yes I haven't verified my server because I don't know how to verify my server, Could you give me. Could you give a reference for how to verify the server ?, Thank you

Comment: try to load a page from the server in the browser and see if it succeeds

Comment: yes, i already test my url "https://192.168.43.172/api/Files/Upload" in browser it is show message  "This site can’t be reached" but if i debug my web service in visual studio my url "https://localhost:44357/" and its success load Home Page from ASP.NET

Comment: if your device cannot reach your server then you obviously have a connectivity issue you need to solve.  Are you sure your web server is setup to allow connections from remote devices?

Comment: yes.maybe my localhost got problem because i need to settings

Comment: @ReyhanManuel Have you check your localhost?

Comment: i already check my localhost cannot load url from browser it is can load localhost if i debug IIS Express, Could you help me how to fix it ?

Comment: I check the steps on youtube, do you start the localhost on edge before you upload?

Comment: my localhost only running in IIS Express, it is cannot running in IIS, How to make running localhost in IIS